# Laravel - Eloquent get submodel by value

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a relation between to models

```
class ModelOne extends Model
{
    public function modelsTwo() {
        return $this->hasMany(ModelTwo::class, 'modeltwo_id');
    }
}
```

Is it posible to retrieve a ModelTwo from ModelOne based on an attribute of ModelTwo?

Something like this for example:

```
$mone = ModelOne::find($id);
$mtwo = $mone->modelsTwo->findByName('foo');
```

So $mtwo will have the ModelTwo from ModelOne with name = 'foo'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you call it as a property `$mone->modelsTwo` it will return all `ModelTwo` records as a `Collection`, and if you call it as a function `$mone->modelsTwo()` it will return a query builder, both has `where()` function that you can use to find a record by a specific name.

```
$mone = ModelOne::find($id);
$mtwo = $mode->modelsTwo->where('name', 'foo')->first();

// or
$mtwo = $mode->modelsTwo()->whereName('foo')->first();
```

If you want to pull all records just simply call it as property but if you want to do a complex query call it as function.

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: A little late but how would this turn out if you had a to find something in a has_many model deeper?